# Replace multiple Strings with Data from CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I've got a CSV (with headers) from all of our access points and want to add them to Zabbix via XML Upload.

Since I don't want to create an XML file for each AP manually, I'll try to do this in PowerShell. But - how?

I've tried some things with `(Get-Content .\Template.xml).Replace()` and `ForEach-Object`, but I haven't had success yet.

Filenames are:

- `AP.csv` (list of APs, headers are Hostname and IP):

  ```
  Hostname;IP
  AP1;10.29.202.101
  AP2;10.29.202.102
  AP3;10.29.202.103
  AP4;10.29.202.104
  Ap5;10.29.202.105
  ```
- `Template.xml`:

  ```xml
  <hosts>
    <host>
      <host>Hostname</host>
      <name>Hostname</name>
      [...]
      <interfaces>
        <interface>
          [...]
          <ip>PIIP</ip>
          [...]
        </interface>
        <interface>
  ```

  The `Template.xml` has 2 strings Called "Hostname" and 2 Called "PIIP" - Both Hostname strings should be replaced with 1 Hostname from `AP.csv`, and both PIIP should be replaced with the related IP.

My Last attempt so far was:

```bsh
$a = Import-Csv .\Ap.csv
$APHost = ($a).Hostname
$APIP = ($a).IP
$xml = Get-Content .\Template.xml
foreach ($row in $a) {
    $xml.Replace('Hostname',$APHost).Replace('PIIP',$APIP) |
        Out-File ".\Aps\$row.xml"
}
```

But this ended in all hostnames and all IPs where in 1 XML file.

I would like to have 1 XML file for each host at the end with hostnames and related IP.

Comment: Please add samples of the xml/csv files you refer to, along with the substitutions you expect, and your attempts so far

Comment: import-csv? have you tried that?

Comment: Updated the Mainpost, Yep, already tried but i don't know how i select only 1 Hostname and the related ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv "$env:userprofile\desktop\Ap.csv" -Delimiter ";"

$template = Get-Content "$env:userprofile\desktop\template.xml" -Raw

$count = 1

foreach ($row in $CSVData) {

    $template.Replace("Hostname", $row.Hostname).Replace("PIIP", $row.IP) |
        Out-File "$env:userprofile\desktop\$count.xml"

    $count++

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your primary problem is:

- you're storing the AP names and IPs in *array* variables outside the loop (`$APHost` and `$APIP`)
- and then use those arrays *as a whole* inside your loop, rather than referencing their elements *one by one*.

Here's a fix, which simply uses `$row.Hostname` and `$row.IP` to get the iteration-appropriate values:

```
$a = Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' .\Ap.csv
$xml = Get-Content -Raw .\Template.xml
foreach ($row in $a) {
    $xml.Replace('Hostname', $row.Hostname).Replace('PIIP', $row.IP) |
      Out-File ".\Aps\$row.xml"
}
```

However, you should **consider using true XML parsing** to make your replacements more robust:

```
$a = Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' .\Ap.csv
$xmlTmpl = [xml] (Get-Content -Raw .\Template.xml)

foreach ($row in $a) {

  # Find the parent Xml element of the elements to update.
  $parentEl = $xmlTmpl.hosts.host

  # Set the hostnames, by element *name*.
  $parentEl.host = $parentEl.name = $row.Hostname

  # Set the IP addresses, by element *name*
  foreach ($el in $parentEl.interfaces.interface.ChildNodes) {
    if ($el.Name -eq 'ip') { $el.InnerText = $row.IP } 
  }

  # XPath alternative (doesn't work in PowerShell *Core*):
  # foreach ($el in $parentEl.SelectNodes('interfaces/interface/ip'))
  # { 
  #   $el.InnerText = $row.IP
  # }

  # Save to file 
  # Note: This doesn't include an XML header.
  $xmlTmpl.OuterXml | Out-File ".\Aps\$row.xml"
}
```

Note how specific elements in specific places in the document hierarchy are targeted, which is a more robust way of instantiating the template (no potential for false positives).